# Reshaping a matrix (numpy array) when matrices are multiplied on individual elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, resize, reshape

I am trying to multiply each element of a 2x2 matrix say [1,1],[1,1] with a 2x2 Identity matrix. The problem is that numpy puts the whole identity matrix as a separate sub index which is not the result I need to evaluate it further, I want it to have 4 rows and 4 columns but when I reshape it to (4,4), it offsets the values and I get [1,0,1,0] on each row (consult the image for required and obtained results).
Thank you!
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IN5JP.png)

EDIT:
Thanks for the response and code.
I made a mistake formulating my question so I'll try one more time.
I have a matrix

```py
I = [[1,0],[0,1]]
A = [
[4*I, 0*I],
[1*(-I), 1*I]
]
```

This should generate the result:

```py
A = [
[4, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 4, 0, 0],
[-1, 0, 1, 0],
[0, -1, 0, 1]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want the Kronecker product.

```
In [585]: np.kron(np.ones((2,2),int), np.eye(2,dtype=int))
Out[585]: 
array([[1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

You were try to make the array with repeated uses of the `eye`:

```
In [590]: np.array([I,I,I])
Out[590]: 
array([[[1, 0],
        [0, 1]],

       [[1, 0],
        [0, 1]],

       [[1, 0],
        [0, 1]]])
```

This is a (3,2,2), that's joining the `eye` on a new leading axis.

It is possible to transpose/reshape the (2,2,2,2) produced by `np.array([[I,I],[I,I]])`, but I'll you with the `kron`.

Comment: I can see this could work as long as I am multiplying each element with I.
My case requires multiplying some with I and some with -I